# iFrame not resizing in desktop

Tags: iframe, iframe-resizer

Hoping someone can help me with getting the iFrame Resizer plugin (https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer) to work correctly.

- My test page is: http://www.chapmancaravans.com.au/new-used/test.php
- The iFrame content has the iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js script added
- I am using the typical setup

When I view the test page on a device (mobile/tablet) it works great. But when I view it on a desktop and reduce the browser window - the iFrame is cut off and does not resize at all.

Does anybody have any suggestions on what I might be missing here?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had a look at your page and the iframed content does not have the iframe.contentwindow.js file loaded into it.

Comment: Thanks David. I thought this had been added. I have asked the site owners again to implement the code... hopefully this will resolve the issues. On another note, will I still need to use the checkOrigin option? And if so can you please explain what values I should be using as I am a little confused about what URLS I need to use. Thanks so much!

Comment: As long as the content in the iframe stays on the same site, port, and protocol; then you don't need to set it.

Comment: I've finally got everything working and am so happy with your plugin! Thanks for your help. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Check your console for errrors

Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('http://chapmansofnowra.caravancampingsales.com.au') does not match the recipient window's origin ('http://www.chapmancaravans.com.au').[image: console messages]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tried adding the 'checkOrigin' option to point to the target origin (same URL used in the iFrame src) but I don't seem to be having any success... It is quite possible I am misunderstanding what I need to do. Can you please clarify?

Comment: That error message is misleading and a bug in Chrome. It's thrown by an iFrame that hasn't loaded. The iframe-resizer has no way of know if an iFrame has loaded when it first runs, so it posts a message to it to see if it's available and then again when the iframe onload event fires. The fist postMessage can cause this error to wrongly appear if the iframe hasn't started loading when it is sent. This however, doesn't stop the next postmessage from working.